# How to find all events that exists and marking whether a particular user has attended? (PostgreSQL, Laravel)

Tags: sql, database, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have to find all the events that exists in events table and to check whether a particular user has attended or not.

There are three tables: users, events and event_user which holds the user_id and events_id. The user_id is already stored in a variable.

My approach is to find all events and then to loop through events.

```
$user_id = 3;
$events = Event::all();
foreach($events as $event){
    $users = $event->users;
    foreach($users as $user){
           if(isset($user->id) && $user->id == $user_id){
                ...perform some adding to the event object
            }
    }
}
```

Is there any simpler, cleaner solution to this problem.

Comment: what are you adding to the object, is it a single value?

Answer (score 1):

I would do the opposite:

```
$user = User::find(3);
$userEvents = $user->events;
$events = Event::all();

foreach ($events as $event) {
    if ($userEvents->contains($event)) {
        // change event object
    }
}
```

So you would have to create a public function in the user class called events.

```
public function events()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
}
```

Comment: This does not return all the events. This return only the events that a particular user has attended. I need all the events.

Comment: I changed the code to include all events, but i'm not sure why you want to go through all events to change only the events that user is in - only do this if you are going to use all the other events in the loop

Comment: Also, if there are like a million events, I definitely wouldn't do Event:all(), this is only if you have a small amount of events. If your goal is to just change some attribute in the user events, then i would only loop though the users events and change those.

Comment: The goal is that in the front-end when a user is logged in and goes to the events section to display different text for every event depending whether they have attended an event or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only setting a single attribute on these Event objects you could do some fun like this:

```
($events = Event::all())
    ->only($user->events()->pluck('id'))
    ->each
    ->setAttribute('something', 'blah');
```